# WebKit and Mozilla render SVG in tables with different sizes

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

The following snippet renders completely differently in Mozilla based browsers (Firefox) when compared to all others (Chrome, Safari, IE, legacy Opera).

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table width="400" height="200" border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="40 40 20 60">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10"></circle>
          </svg>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0b9cukLo/

In WebKit/IE the table is sized as requested at 400x200, and the SVG scales to fill that space (vertical space is the limiting factor).  In Mozilla the SVG scales to fill the allocated 400px of *horizontal* space, leaving the vertical dimension to stretch out the table.

Is this a Mozilla bug?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!